# How to use redux in react component with withNavigation together

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I am trying to connect some component(Header) to my redux store.
I already succeed to connect the store from other component and it's worked,
I think I have a problem in connecting the store because of the use of withNavigation in the Component.
Any idea on why my component is not connecting to the store?

My reducer

```js
import articles from '../../constants/articles'
const intialState = {
  orderList: articles,
  name: "Please work"
  
};

const orderReducer = (state = intialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
     ....
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default orderReducer;
```

My Header component that not connect

```js
import React from 'react';
import { withNavigation } from '@react-navigation/compat';
...
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
....

class Header extends React.Component{
...
  const { back, title, white, transparent, bgColor, iconColor, titleColor, navigation, ...props } = this.props;
...

  return (
    <Block style={headerStyles}>
      <Block>
      //************the warn that displayed is "undeinded"****************
        {console.warn(this.props.name)}
        .....
    </Block>
  );
  
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
...
});
const mapStateToProps = state =>{
  return{
    name: state.name
  }
}

export default withNavigation(connect(mapStateToProps)(Header))
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? Are you facing any error or it just warn name as undefined?

Comment: Thanks for wanting to help, I'm not getting an error/warning message,
I'm trying to access the redux store by using  "this.props.name"
but I get the value "undeinded"

Comment: Can you try with `this.props.orderList`?

Comment: I change the map func to but it is still  "undeinded":
 const mapStateToProps = state =>{
  return{
    name: state.name
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

I understad what was the mistake,
I tried to connect the store by using

```js
const mapStateToProps = state =>{
  return{
    name: state.name
  }
}
```

but I did"t know that I supposed to add  orderReducer  like this:

```js
const mapStateToProps = state =>{
  return{
    name: state.orderReducer.name
  }
}
```